# Remove specific characters except last

Tags: c#, string, character

I have a text string and I want to replace the dots with underscores except for the last character found in the string.

Example:

```
input = "video.coffee.example.mp4"
result = "video_coffe_example.mp4"
```

I have a code but this replaces everything including the last character

first option failed

```
static string replaceForUnderScore(string file)
{
     return file = file.Replace(".", "_");
}
```

I implemented a second option that works for me but I find that it is very extensive and not very optimized

```
static string replaceForUnderScore(string file)
{
     string result = "";

     var splits = file.Split(".");
     var extension = splits.LastOrDefault();

     splits = splits.Take(splits.Count() - 1).ToArray();

     foreach (var strItem in splits)
     {
         result = result + "_" + strItem;
     }

     result = result.Substring(1, result.Length-1);
     string finalResult = result + "."+extension;

     return finalResult;
 }
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If these are really filenames, I would first use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` to get the filename, replace _all_ dots with underscores and then connect again together with the result of `Path.GetExtension`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you work with files, I suggest using [Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0) class: all
we want is to change *file name* only while keeping *extension* intact:

```
static string replaceForUnderScore(string file) =>
  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Replace('.', '_') + Path.GetExtension(file);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex will help you to do this.

Add the namespace `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

And use this code:

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape("."));
var newText = regex.Replace("video.coffee.example.mp4", "_", 2);
```

Here we specified the maximum number of times to replace the `.`

The output would be the following:

```
video_coffee_example.mp4
```

Additionally, you can update the code to replace **any number** of dots excluding the last one.

```
    var replaceChar = '.';
    var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(replaceChar.ToString()));
    var replaceWith = "_";
    // The text to process
    var text = "video.coffee.example.mp4";
    // Count how many chars to replace excluding extension
    var replaceCount = text.Count(s => s == replaceChar) - 1;
    var newText = regex.Replace(text, replaceWith, replaceCount);
```

Comment: hello, the problem is that they will not always be 2, since the points can be 3, 4, 5.... Wouldn't it be a solution to count the characters to be eliminated and subtract one?

Comment: @AlonsoContreras Well, yes, you can input the count of dots to remove. I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the dots with an underscore except for the last dot by asserting that there is still a dot present to the right when matching one.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\.(?=[^.]*\.)", "_");
```

The *result* will be

```
video_coffee_example.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head but this might work.

```
return $"{file.Replace(".mp4","").Replace(".","_")}.mp4";
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and probably fastest) way is just to iterate over the string:

```cs
static string replaceForUnderScore(string file)
{
  StringBuilder sb      = new StringBuilder( file.Length ) ;
  int           lastDot = -1 ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; i < file.Length ; ++i )
  {
    char c = file[i] ;

    // if we found a '.', replace it with '_' and save its position
    if ( c == '.' )
    {
      c       = '_' ;
      lastDot = i   ;
    }


    sb.Append( c ) ;

  }

  // if we changed any '.' to '_', convert the last such replacement back to '.'
  if ( lastDot >= 0 )
  {
    sb.Replace ( '.' , '_' , lastDot, 1 );
  }

  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Another approach would be to use `System.IO.Path`. It's certainly the most succinct:

```
static string replaceForUnderScore( string file )
{
  string ext  = Path.GetExtension( file ) ;
  string name = Path
                .GetFileNameWithoutExtension( file )
                .Replace( '.' , '_' )
                ;

  return Path.ChangeExtension( name , ext ) ;
}
```